# Not able to download the attachments

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I am tying to download the attachments using jersey restful services.

below is my code snippet :

```
if(entity != null) {
    ResourceStream stream = new ResourceStream(entity);
    return Response.ok(stream.getResponse(), entity.getMediatype()).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + entity.getName() + "\" ").build();
}
```

Above code returns below response:

```
Apr 18, 2017 12:06:23 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/pdf, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse.
```

Comment: Could you please post your method? I think the annotations you use are important to diagnostic the issue.

Comment: Please change the question title to "Not able to download the attachments" So it can be reached by more peoples accurately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the annotation on your sub-resource method to

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
```

And Create file object like

```
File file = new File("Location of the file with file name");
```

and send the response like this

```
if (file.exists()) {
  ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(file);
  builder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
response = builder.build();
```

and return response

```
return builder;
```

For more info

[jersey file upload and download example](https://gist.github.com/aitoroses/4f7a2b197b732a6a691d)